# Issue using Phoenix JDBC with Squirrel SQL

Tags: jdbc, apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

I am trying to connect Squirrel SQL to an Apache Phoenix database, but instead getting the below error:

```
Could not find class org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver in neither
the Java class path nor the Extra class path of the ARAF_Phoenix driver definition:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
```

I have already added the Phoenix-client.jar file to the lib folder of squirrel application. Not sure, but please help if I have missed any setting that needs to be done.

Attaching the screenshots as well.
Note : I have deleted the IP from the driver connection wizard.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add Driver-->Extra Class Path--> ADD (Select the JAR file required) --> update Name,Example URL--> Click on "List Drivers" ---> Click OK

This should fix your issue